# Assigning a vector to a matrix row in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have array (vector) `r =[2 4]` and `report` matrix with size 50*2. I want put `r` in row 1 of `report` matrix.
When I run

```
with report(1)=r;
```

MATLAB returns this error:

> ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I
>   must be the same.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
report(1,:)=r
```

You need to specify the columns as well. Otherwise `report(1)` is a scalar, `r` is a vector, and you get an error.

Comment: This answer OVERWRITES the current values in line 1 in report(1,:), for a way to ADD r BEFORE the existing rows in report, you can use user1319936's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something you simply want to have a vector as the first row of a matrix:

`report = [r;report]`

Comment: @angainor 's answer overwrites the current values in line 1 in report(1,:), for a way to ADD r BEFORE the existing rows in report, you can use this answer.

Please note that it takes exponentially much longer time than angainor's answer as the table gets bigger, just in case you want to add thousands of lines in this way!